# Cakephp 1.2 this->set not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

So I am setting a variable to be used in view.
This happens during a form POST. Maybe this can give some hints to someone.

```
public function confirm_card(){
            if(!isset ($this->data['UserPayment']) && empty($this->data['UserPayment'])){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__d('payments', 'Select payment method', true), 'flash_error');
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
            else{
                foreach($this->data['UserPayment'] as $key=>$up){                    
                    if(!empty($up)){                        
                        $this->set(array('paytype'=>$key));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And in view

```
echo $paytype;
```

Result in view

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: paytype
```

The key is returned as it should be so no empty values there.
This should be very basic... I am missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$this->set('paytype', $key);
```

Change

```
 $this->redirect($this->referer());
```

The problem was `!empty($up)` vs `$up != ''` ?

`$up` is normally 0 or 1 ?

Comment: maybe $this->set('paytype', $key); I did that already and it's not working

Comment: why are you using `$this->redirect($this->render());` ? Maybe you want to do `$this->redirect($this->referer());` ? You are only setting `paytype` in the `else`.

Comment: da, corect :) haha, but anyway that was not the issue here. This is strange coz it should just work...

Comment: ah one more thing maybe this is important. this is happening after a POST

Comment: can you debug `$this->data['UserPayment']` ? You are only setting the variable is `$up` is not empty. Maybe you do not have those values.

Comment: OK so based on your answer the problem was here if(!empty($up)) now i check if $up returns a value and it's everything OK. You can edit your answer so I can accept it